# delete page is not working

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system

I am creating a cms and have set up all the pages perfectly but the delete page.

I have this code for my delete.php:

```
<?php

session_start();

include_once('../include/connection.php');
include_once('../include/article.php');

$article = new Article;

if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
    $articles = $article->fetch_all();
?>    
<html>
<head>
<title>testing</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css" />
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
<a href="index.php" id="logo">CMS</a>

<br /><br />

<form action="delete.php" method="get">
     <select onchange="this.form.submit();">
<?php foreach ($articles as $article){ ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $article['article_id']; ?>"><?php echo $article['article_title']; ?></option>
<php } ?>
     </select>
</form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
} else {
     header('Location: index.php');

}
?>
```

But in my error log It is telling me this:

PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in /delete.php on line 37

Line 37 is "} else {" please can someone advise me as to where I am going wrong?

thank you.

Comment: `<php } ?>` should be `<?php } ?>`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about too localized.

Comment: `<php } ?>` missing a `?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your php opening tag is invalid. Change

```
< php } ?>
```

to

```
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: thank you so much. this works fine. I should have seen that (text book error). Thanks for your help.